# Why I am Getting value of NSString like 0xb000000000000033 in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I am new to `iOS` and I have written code like this

```
 NSString *Mobilenumber =[firstObj valueForKey:@"MobilNo"];
    NSLog(@"Mobile Number is =%@",Mobilenumber);
    NSString *Employeeid=[firstObj valueForKey:@"EmpId"];
    NSLog(@"Employee ID is =%@",Employeeid);
```

Mobile Number gives me correct value while `Employeeid` give me value like this  0xb000000000000033. But when I `NSLog` the Employeeid it shows value as 3.

But when I compair it with the value of another text

```
if ([EmployeeStr isEqual:techString])
```

it doesn't go to `if` condition but both the string contain the same value. How to solve this type of value 0xb000000000000033.

Comment: What is `firstObj`?

Comment: May be the firstObj containing the @"EmpId" is not a string value...so do one thing, just type cast it NSString *Employeeid = (NSString *)[firstObj valueForKey:@"EmpId"];

Comment: probably it is again returning number and you are trying to get `empId` inside string ..

Comment: your `EmpId` may not be string. It may be `NSNumber`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// i think you getting NSNumber object for that key "EmpId" 
just try like this, i hope it will work for you.

```
 NSString *Employeeid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [firstObj valueForKey:@"EmpId"]]
```

Comment: Thanks Your Code Work.

Answer (score 2):

Might be help you

```
NSString *EmployeeId = [firstObj valueForKey:@"EmpId"];
NSLog(@"Employee ID is =%@",EmployeeId);
NSString *strEmployeeId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [firstObj valueForKey:@"EmpId"]];
NSLog(@"Str Employee ID is =%@",strEmployeeId);
NSString *castEmployeeId = (NSString *)[firstObj valueForKey:@"EmpId"];
NSLog(@"Cast Employee ID is =%@",castEmployeeId);
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *Mobilenumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[firstObj valueForKey:@"MobilNo"]];
NSLog(@"Mobile Number is =%@",Mobilenumber);
NSString *Employeeid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[firstObj valueForKey:@"EmpId"]];
NSLog(@"Employee ID is =%@",Employeeid);
```

& then compare its work...

```
if ([Employeeid isEqualToString:techString])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `%p` should work for any pointer -

```
NSString *Mobilenumber =[firstObj valueForKey:@"MobilNo"];
    NSLog(@"Mobile Number is =%@",Mobilenumber);
    NSString *Employeeid=[firstObj valueForKey:@"EmpId"];
    NSLog(@"Employee ID is =%@",Employeeid);
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", Employeeid];
 NSLog(@"Employee ID is =%@",address);
```

OR

Convert it to an integer & do the rest of thing -

```
NSUInteger myInt = [ Employeeid integerValue ];
char * ptr       = ( char * )myInt;
```

Comment: I have Just Change NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Employeeid]; And I works. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Muju If you find it helpful, upvote it , which will help others.